# Динамическое изменение размера QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qtextedit, qplaintextedit

Текущее поведение `QTextEdit` при изменении размеров окна:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Необходимое поведение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(228, 106)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 1, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 50))
        self.textEdit.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 1, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста </p></body></html>"))
```

---

Есть ли возможность добиться такого поведения от `QTextEdit` без создания нового класса?

При создании нового класса, как получить необходимые размеры, для передачи в `SizeHint`?

---

**Update**:

Видимо из сообщения не совсем понятно в чём проблема.
Необходимо, чтобы при изменении размеров окна, `QTextEdit` занимал ровно столько места, сколько требуется для отображения текста внутри него.

Маленькое окно - `QTextEdit` становится больше и не обрезает\скрывает текст, большое окно - `QTextEdit` уменьшается, т.к. в нём появляется пустое пространство.

Comment: Можно указать Fixed Height или вместо QTextEdit использовать QLineEdit

Comment: @gil9red при указании `setFixedHeight` появится полоса прокрутки для текста, который не поместился. С `QLineEdit` же вообще не будет адекватного отображения текста, т.к. он его обрежет при уменьшении.

Comment: Действительно, `QLineEdit` по умолчанию, обрезает текст длиною больше 32767 (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#maxLength-prop). А полосу QTextEdit прокрутки можно и убрать. А вам как нужно? Опишите, тогда, в вопросе подробнее, какое поведение нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> lineWrapMode : LineWrapMode
> Это свойство содержит режим переноса строки
>
> Режим по умолчанию - WidgetWidth, который заставляет слова переноситься по правому краю редактируемого текста. Перенос происходит по пробелам, сохраняя целые слова нетронутыми. Если вы хотите, чтобы перенос слов происходил, используйте setWordWrapMode(). Если вы установили режим переноса FixedPixelWidth или FixedColumnWidth, вы также должны вызвать setLineWrapColumnOrWidth() с желаемой шириной.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(228, 106)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 1, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 50))
        self.textEdit.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 1, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста </p></body></html>"))    


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.textEdit.setLineWrapMode(QtWidgets.QTextEdit.NoWrap) 
        
        self.textEdit.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.textEdit.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        
        self.textEdit.setFixedWidth(
            self.textEdit.document().documentLayout().documentSize().width()
            + self.textEdit.width()
            - self.textEdit.viewport().width()
        )

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

Я не понимаю, почему вы не напишите мне, что не так в моем ответе? Попробую угадать, что вы хотите еще раз.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(228, 106)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 1, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 50))
        self.textEdit.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 1, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста </p></body></html>"))


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.textEdit.setLineWrapMode(QtWidgets.QTextEdit.NoWrap) 
        
        self.textEdit.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.textEdit.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        
        self.textEdit.setFixedWidth(
            self.textEdit.document().documentLayout().documentSize().width()
            + self.textEdit.width()
            - self.textEdit.viewport().width()
        )
        self.textEdit.setFixedHeight(
            self.textEdit.document().documentLayout().documentSize().height()
            + self.textEdit.height()
            - self.textEdit.viewport().height()
        )
        
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update 2**

> в вашем ответе неправильно то, что размер QTextEdit становится фиксированным. При увеличении окна QTextEdit сохраняет свой размер, а уменьшить окно вообще нельзя

Как понимал, так и написал.
Когда задаете вопрос, старайтесь дать столько подробностей,
чтобы вопрос был понятен и другим, а не только вам.

По сути: самый простой способ заменить виджет `QTextEdit` на `QPlainTextEdit` .

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(228, 106)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 1, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)

#        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)        # +++ !!!

        self.textEdit.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 50))
        self.textEdit.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 1, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

        self.textEdit.setPlainText(_translate("MainWindow", "Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста "))
        ''' 
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста </p></body></html>"))
        '''

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.textEdit.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.textEdit.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  

        self.textEdit.appendHtml("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста Образец текста </p></body></html>")
      
        self.textEdit.updateRequest.connect(self.handle_updateRequest)         # !!!
        self.handle_updateRequest(QtCore.QRect(), 0)                           

    def handle_updateRequest(self, rect, dy):
        doc = self.textEdit.document()
        tb = doc.findBlockByNumber(doc.blockCount() - 1)
        h = self.textEdit.blockBoundingGeometry(tb).bottom() + 2 * doc.documentMargin()
        self.textEdit.setFixedHeight(h)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @SNick в вашем ответе неправильно то, что размер  `QTextEdit` становится фиксированным. При увеличении окна `QTextEdit` сохраняет свой размер, а уменьшить окно вообще нельзя

Comment: @Skeggi я добавил обновление в свой ответ.

Comment: @SNick Спасибо. Теперь то, что нужно. По поводу понятности: заголовок - "Динамическое изменение размеров" уже подразумевает, что размеры не статичны(фиксированы). В Update же дополнительно указано, что размеры `QTextEdit` должны изменяться - становиться больше\меньше

Comment: @SNick не нашел как написать личное сообщение. Наблюдая за вашими ответами, у меня не мог не возникнуть вопрос:"Откуда вы так хорошо знаете Qt?" Очевидно, что практика решает, но практики без теории нет. Какая литература поможет узнать различные тонкости Qt? Прохоренок и Дронов? Или же какая-то иностранная литература?

Comment: @Skeggi Терпение и труд всё перетрут. Вы верно подметили - практика решает всё. 
Я лично стараюсь отслеживать все, что публикуется о PyQt и вопросы, и ответы, и статьи, и на youtube, и на github, и на всех сайтах stackoverflow. 
А главное то, что я уже научился читать и понимать документацию 
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework , чего и вам желаю. 
Это придет, но надо потрудиться. Если мои ответы дают вам новые знания, не забывайте отмечать их как полезные. Удачи вам.