# Данные в виде таблицы, но не QTableWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

Необходимо что-то похожее на такую структуру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Особенности:

1. Текст в первой ячейке с левого края и по центру, в остальных - по центру.
2. При изменении размеров таблицы изменяется длина и высота ячеек.
3. Высота ячейки подгоняется под её содержимое, как в ответе на мой предыдущий вопрос [Динамическое изменение размера QTextEdit](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1202117/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-qtextedit)

Сразу же отбросил мысль о использовании `QTableWidget`, т.к. ячейки статичны. Решил использовать измененный `QPlainTextEdit` из предыдущего вопроса + `QGridLayout`, но столкнулся с проблемой - из-за разного количества данных в ячейках, высоты у них тоже разные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотел передавать ячейкам высоту самой большой, но другая проблема - текст в ячейках располагается не по центру, а сверху и изменить этого нельзя, т.к. `QPlainTextEdit` не знает что такое высота, а следовательно, где центр в вертикальной плоскости.
Тогда решил схитрить и поместил `QPlainTextEdit` в `QFrame` + `QGridLayout` и залил фон у `QFrame`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class PlainTextEdit(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PlainTextEdit, self).__init__(parent)

    def text_to_center(self):
        self.updateRequest.connect(lambda: self.handle_updateRequest(self))

    def handle_updateRequest(self, a):
        doc = a.document()
        tb = doc.findBlockByNumber(doc.blockCount() - 1)
        h = a.blockBoundingGeometry(tb).bottom() + 2 * doc.documentMargin()
        a.setFixedHeight(h)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)

        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("QFrame{background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);}")

        self.frame1 = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.frame1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.frame1.setMaximumHeight(65)
        self.vlay1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame1)
        self.textEdit1 = PlainTextEdit(self.frame1)
        self.textEdit1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.textEdit1.setPlainText('GoGOGO GoGOGO GoGOGO')
        self.textEdit1.text_to_center()
        self.vlay1.addWidget(self.textEdit1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.frame1, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.frame2 = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.frame2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.frame2.setMaximumHeight(65)
        self.vlay2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame2)
        self.textEdit2 = PlainTextEdit(self.frame2)
        self.textEdit2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.textEdit2.setPlainText('GoGOGO GoGOGO')
        self.textEdit2.text_to_center()
        self.vlay2.addWidget(self.textEdit2)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.frame2, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.frame3 = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.frame3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.frame3.setMaximumHeight(65)
        self.vlay3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame3)
        self.textEdit3 = PlainTextEdit(self.frame3)
        self.textEdit3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.textEdit3.setPlainText('GoGOGO')
        self.textEdit3.text_to_center()
        self.vlay3.addWidget(self.textEdit3)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.frame3, 0, 2, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Window()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И результат-то меня устраивает. Ячейки ведут себя так, как надо, но... Костыль же + в 2 раза больше объектов.

#### Вопросы:

1. Можно ли всё таки изменить `QTableWidget` так, чтобы появилось необходимое поведение?
2. Есть ли более элегантное решение на основе `QPlainTextEdit`?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если так:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        items = [
            ['Поле 1:\n' * 3, '123\n' * 2, 'abc ' * 10],
            ['Поле 2:\n' * 3, '456\n' * 2, 'def ' * 10],
        ]

        self.setRowCount(len(items))
        self.setColumnCount(len(items[0]))

        for col in range(self.columnCount()):
            self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(col, QHeaderView.Stretch)

        for row in range(self.rowCount()):
            item = QTableWidgetItem(items[row][0])
            self.setItem(row, 0, item)

            item = QTableWidgetItem(items[row][1])
            item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.setItem(row, 1, item)

            item = QTableWidgetItem(items[row][2])
            item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.setItem(row, 2, item)

        self.resizeRowsToContents()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не подходит, т.к. при изменении главного окна изменяется размер только последней колонки

Comment: @Skeggi, а нужно равномерно?

Comment: Вообще нужно, чтобы растяжение можно было регулировать, но дабы не усложнять вопрос, не указал этого. Если ячейки будут реагировать на изменение размеров таблицы, найду способ как управлять этим. Если будут равномерно растягиваться, то такой вариант тоже подойдёт

Comment: @Skeggi, обновил ответ

Comment: а это уже похоже на желаемое. Спасибо

Comment: @Skeggi, хех, пожалуйста :)